# How to achieve data search in python list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a newbie to python and I need some guidance. What is the best way of iterating through the list below.

```
[('admincases', 'test_case_6'), ('admincases', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_9'),('admincases1', 'test_case_10')]
```

First I want to get all the admincases unique value like:

```
['admincases', 'admincases1']
```

Then iterating through the above cases I should get the list of test for the specified case:

```
'admincase'
  ['test_case_6', 'test_case_8']
'admincase1'
  ['test_case_8', 'test_case_9', 'test_case_10']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html)

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> l = [('admincases', 'test_case_6'), ('admincases', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_9'),('admincases1', 'test_case_10')]
>>> for k,v in l:
...    d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> d['admincases']
['test_case_6', 'test_case_8']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> itertools.groupby(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
<itertools.groupby object at 0x7fb79740aa48>
>>> list(itertools.groupby(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
[('admincases', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fb797405a10>), ('admincases1', <itertools._grouper object at 0x7fb797405a50>)]
>>> [(x[0], list(x[1])) for x in itertools.groupby(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0))]
[('admincases', [('admincases', 'test_case_6'), ('admincases', 'test_case_8')]), ('admincases1', [('admincases1', 'test_case_8'), ('admincases1', 'test_case_9'), ('admincases1', 'test_case_10')])]
```

Be sure your input is sorted by the key first though.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lis= [('admincases', 'test_case_6'), ('admincases', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_9'),('admincases1', 'test_case_10')]

>>> lis1=list({x[0] for x in lis}) #returns ['admincases', 'admincases1']

>>> dic={y:[x[1] for x in lis if x[0]==y]for y in lis1}
>>> dic
{'admincases': ['test_case_6', 'test_case_8'], 'admincases1': ['test_case_8', 'test_case_9', 'test_case_10']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to @BurhanKhalid's solution using `dict.setdefault` instead of `defaultdict`. I prefer `defaultdict` but apparently this is faster if the default value does not take a long time to construct.

```
>>> L = [('admincases', 'test_case_6'), ('admincases', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_8'),('admincases1', 'test_case_9'),('admincases1', 'test_case_10')]
>>> D = {}
>>> for k,v in L:
        D.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)


>>> D['admincases']
['test_case_6', 'test_case_8']
```